# Getting only a substring of matching strings with RexEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to filter certain strings within a large text file. I want to get the strings starting with a certain word and ending with quotation marks, but only the last part of this string starting from the last dot in this word. To be more precise, I am searching for class names within a document, starting with the base namespace, but I don't need the fully qualified classname, only the class name itself. (e.g. not `"NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.Classname"`, only `"Classname"`.

As an example, from this string:

```
sddkjasd"fhadslkfhdskljfahskjff"shkdfjhfkhafklj"NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.ClassnameA"swenbfjiwguzl"lgvfdu"eQVFZEIW"NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.ClassnameB"VDTZEvwqdtzevdzgi
```

I want these matches:

```
ClassnameA
ClassnameB
```

`NamespaceA` will always be the same, so I can use this as a starting condition, and the closing quot. marks will always be there, so I can use them as the end condition, but I don't know how to select only the last work starting from the last dot out of this with a regex. Of course I could work a way around this, e.g. using string manipulation on the result (which is what I am doing right now), or using a second regex on the result, but I am interested if there is a way by getting this result directly with a regex. Currently, I am matching with `NamespaceA.+?(?=\")` to get the full namespace without the closing quot. marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negated character class to make the regex engine to match any character but not of `"` or dot, so that it won't greedily match the dot or quotes.

```
"NamespaceA.*?\.([^."]*)"
```

OR

```
"NamespaceA[^"]*?\.([^."]*)"
```

Use any one of the above regexes and get the classnames from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aC1qF2/2)

**Code:**

```
String input = @"sddkjasd""fhadslkfhdskljfahskjff""shkdfjhfkhafklj""NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.ClassnameA""swenbfjiwguzl""lgvfdu""eQVFZEIW""NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.ClassnameB""VDTZEvwqdtzevdzgi";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"NamespaceA[^""]*?\.([^.""]*)""");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/L9aDt9)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NamespaceA(?:\.\w+)*\.(\w+)
```

The classNames will be in group 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Namespace.*?\.(?=\w+")(\w+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/1